# References for affine groups of $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups, affine-geometry

I should study  affine group $\operatorname{Aff} (\mathbb R^n)$ in a Lie group and Lie  algebras course but I have  almost no  information about it. So please if some one can suggest any books or links for more information about this subject, I will be very grateful !

Comment: See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_group) and the references there. What exactly do you need about the affine group and the affine Lie algebra? Is it about semidirect products, is it about geometry? Can you give a little bit more context?

Comment: Thank you ! I need to know for example how to prove  that $Aff(\mathbb R^n)\cong \mathbb R^n \ltimes  GL(n,\mathbb R)$ and some other results about semidirect products, left invariants vector fields, the exponential map and Lie algebra of $Aff(\mathbb R^n)$...

Answer (score 2):

The affine group ${\rm Aff}(V)$ for a vector space $V$ is by definition given by $GL(V)\ltimes V$. It is easy to see that it is isomorphic to the group of  *affine transformations*
$L_{A,v}\colon V\rightarrow V, \; x\mapsto Ax+v$. What is its Lie algebra?

Recall that the semidirect product $\mathfrak{g} \ltimes V$ with abelian Lie algebra $V$ becomes a Lie algebra by
\begin{align*}
[(x,v),(y,w)] & = ([x,y], D(x)(w)-D(y)(v)),
\end{align*}
for $x,y\in \mathfrak{g}$ and $v,w\in V$ and a representation $D\colon \mathfrak{g} \rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}(V)$.

For $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{gl}(V)$ and $D={\rm id}$ we obtain the Lie algebra
$$
\mathfrak{aff} (V):=\mathfrak{gl}(V)\ltimes V
$$
with Lie bracket $[(A,v),(B,w)]=([A,B], Aw-Bv)$. Identifying $V$ with $\Bbb R^n$, we obtain that $\mathfrak{aff}(V)$ is isomorphic
to the following subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}_{n+1}(\Bbb R)$:
$$
\mathfrak{aff} (V) \cong \left \{ \begin{pmatrix} A & v \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \mid A \in M_n(\Bbb R),\,
v\in \Bbb R^n \right \}.
$$
The Lie bracket here is given by the commutator of matrices,

$$
\Bigl[  \begin{pmatrix} A & v \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, 
 \begin{pmatrix} B & w \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \Bigr] = 
 \begin{pmatrix} [A,B] & Aw-Bv \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} 
$$

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer Mr. Burde!